# I want connect.php file should be run in local host

Tags: php

This my online connect.php code

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('test', 'test', 'test');
$db=mysql_select_db('test');
?>
```

Comment: [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) FTW ;)

Comment: @codaddict, he is facing the problem of "not able to define his problem".

Answer (score 1):

> I want connect.php file should be run in local host

I'll take a stab in the dark.

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test');
$db=mysql_select_db('test');
?>
```

[Further Reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question) :P